# Save the data of Mat (OpenCV) on memoryarea located by a pointer

Tags: opencv, pointers, opencl, mat

I have created a memory object on the shared memory with following OpenCL-Function call:

```
cl_mem buffer_img_GAUSS_TEST = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR, sizeof(uchar) * size_cols * size_rows,NULL,&status);
```

A call of this function gives me the pointer:

```
uchar *src_ptr;
src_ptr  = (uchar *)clEnqueueMapBuffer(cmdQueue, buffer_img_GAUSS_TEST, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_READ, 0, sizeof(uchar) * size_cols* size_rows, 0, NULL, NULL, &status);
```

Now I want to read an image with following OpenCV function call:

```
Mat img= imread( "scene.jpg", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE );
```

Is it possible to "say" that the data of the picture should be placed at the data-area pointed to by src_ptr? The area located by the buffer_img_GAUSS_TEST has exactly the size needed for the data of Template

In other words:
I want to replace this part of the code, which copys the data from the Image to the address pointed to by src_pointer.

```
memcpy ( src_ptr, img.data, sizeof(uchar) * img.cols * img.rows);
```

Answer (score 2):

No.
According to [cv::Mat](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html) design it is impossible to load image data at specified memory location.

The proper way is to use memcpy (as you do). Move semantics for cv::Mat is undefined (at least I haven't seen anything like that and there is no information in docs).
The other solution is to provide pointer to img data (by calling cv::Mat::data()) without creating a copy of image, if there is such ability in other lib you use. In this case you should implement some kind of shared ownership and no deallocate cv::Mat while pointer to its data is in use.